# DETECTLANGUAGE with URL as input variable

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, url, scrape, language-detection

I have a huge list of domains (20k) and want to detect which language is used on each domain. I saw that there is a great function called DETECTLANGUAGE(), but i am not sure, how to get some text snippets from the website´s continous text. In addition to that, I think that i will run into some limitations, when using IMPORTXML or IMPORTDATA here.

Any ideas?